# Confused how to create Django forms with radio buttons.

Tags: python, django

This is my forms.py.

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms


class Blog(models.Model):
    blog_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class TumblrForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ('blog_id',)
        widgets = {
            'blog_id':forms.RadioSelect(),
        }
```

How to declare this in a view and show a list of radiobuttons.

Comment: a radio button for char field? why? radio buttons are usually used for choices e.g. boolean

Comment: Basically the user has to select a blog from the list of blogs that I plan to show. Any other than radio button would work too.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in a form you want to show list of blogs to choose from, a drop down list is required here:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    blog = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label=_("Blog"),
        queryset=Blog.objects.all())
```

Comment: Not exactly. Here I've to modify the model once the user selects a particular blog. In your case, how do I declare this in a view once I've a list of blogs.

Comment: Ok my first comment is just confusing you more. I do not understand what you are trying to say here. Are you saying that you have list of blogs in your view and you need to create a form to display them?

Comment: Yes. And a user selects one of those blogs, presses a button, and the form gets submitted to be update the DB.